# SilverStripe CheckboxSetField Defaults

Tags: silverstripe

Hi I'm using SilverStripe 2.4.7

[Docs](http://api.silverstripe.org/2.4/forms/fields-basic/CheckboxSetField.html#methodsetDefaultItems)

I am generating around 250+ checkboxes, using a DataObjectSet of DataObjects, and want all of them to be checked by default. I tried passing the same array that populates the checkboxsetfield to the setDefaultItems method like so...

```
$checkBox->setDefaultItems( $values );
```

but that didn't work. I'm completely stumped as I can't find anything else that even hints at how to do this and I'm getting desperate.

I just keep getting this error.

```
in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm aware that I need to pass an array instead of an object but when I use toArray() it throws back another error.  Object of class Value could not be converted to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are passing an associative array with key/value pairs, when what it's after is an indexed array, with only the key (checkbox value).

Try

```
$checkBox->setDefaultItems( array_keys($values) );
```

Comment: Hi @Shea Dawson.  When I put that in I got this error. "array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given" so I tried adding ->toArray() and that sort of worked. It not checks the checkbox with the lowest ID only.  Odd.

Comment: Got it. Turned out doing a foreach and pushing the ID of the value to the array worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. :) This is why I love StackOverflow. Helpful, knowledgable people who are happy to help out.